# istream leads to console printing doubles

Tags: c++, pointers, console-application

I am having trouble figuring out why my code is printing outputs twice to the console. I'm sure it's some small detail that I missed but I have been working at this for the whole day and I need a fresh pair of eyes.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//Allows use of basic C++ functions
using namespace std;

//Base class for all classes
class Person
{
protected:
    string m_Name, m_Surname, m_Telephone, m_Email;
public:
    Person() {}
    Person(string &s, string &f) : m_Surname(s), m_Name(f)
    {
        m_Name = "NoName", m_Surname = "NoSurname", m_Telephone = "", m_Email = "";
    }

    void set_name(string &f)
    {
        m_Name = f;
    }

    void set_surname(string &s)
    {
        m_Surname = s;
    }

    virtual string get_name()
    {
        return m_Name;
    }

    virtual string get_surname()
    {
        return m_Surname;
    }

    virtual string get_telephone()
    {
        return m_Telephone;
    }

    virtual string get_email()
    {
        return m_Email;
    }

    virtual bool has_telephone_p()
    {

        if (m_Telephone.empty())
        {
            //cout << "NoNumber" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //cout << "Your phone number is now registered"<< endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

    virtual bool has_email_p()
    {
        if (m_Email.empty())
        {
            //cout << "NoEmail" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //cout << "Your email is now registered" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
};

//Inherits from class Person
class Person_with_telephone : public virtual Person
{
protected:
    string telephone = m_Telephone;
public:
    Person_with_telephone() {}
    Person_with_telephone(string &s, string &f, string &t) : Person(s, f), telephone(t) {}

    void set_telephone(string &telephone)
    {
        m_Telephone = telephone;
    }
};

//Inherits from class Person
class Person_with_email : public virtual Person
{
protected:
    string email = m_Email;
public:
    Person_with_email() {}
    Person_with_email(string &s, string &f, string &e) :Person(s, f), email(e) {}

    void set_email(string &e)
    {
        m_Email = e;
    }
};

//Inherits from classes Person_with_telephone and Person_and_email
class Person_with_telephone_email : public virtual Person_with_telephone, public virtual Person_with_email
{
protected:

public:
    Person_with_telephone_email() {}
    Person_with_telephone_email(string &s, string &f, string &t, string &e) : Person(s, f), Person_with_telephone(s, f, t), Person_with_email(s, f, e) {}
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &output, Person &p)
{
    //Checks that both 'telephone' and 'email' are initialized to NoNumber and NoEmail respectively. If true, it prints name and surname
    if (p.has_telephone_p() == false && p.has_email_p() == false)
    {
        output << "<person" << " S " << p.get_surname() << " N " << p.get_name() << " >" << endl;
        return output;
    }
    //Checks that 'email' is initialized to NoEmail. If true, it prints name, surname, and telephone
    else if (p.has_email_p() == false)
    {
        output << "<person" << " S " << p.get_surname() << " N " << p.get_name() << " T " << p.get_telephone() << " >" << endl;
        return output;
    }
    //Checks that 'telephone' is initialized to NoNumber. If true, it prints name, surname, and email
    else if (p.has_telephone_p() == false)
    {
        output << "<person" << " S " << p.get_surname() << " N " << p.get_name() << " E " << p.get_email() << " >" << endl;
        return output;
    }
    //Checks to see that all 4 variables are initialized to non default values. If true, it prints all 4 values
    else
    {
        output << "<person" << " S " << p.get_surname() << " N " << p.get_name() << " T " << p.get_telephone() << " E " << p.get_email() << " >";
        return output;
    }
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person &p) {
    string opening, s, surname, f, name, closing;

    if (
        (is >> opening >> s >> surname >> f >> name >> closing)
        &&
        ((opening == "<person") && (s == "S") && (f == "N") && (closing == ">"))
        )
{
        p = Person(surname, name);
}
    return is;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person_with_email &p) {
    string opening, s, surname, f, name, e, email, closing;

    if (
        (is >> opening >> s >> surname >> f >> name >> e >> email >> closing) &&
        ((opening == "<person") && (s == "S") && (f == "N") && (e == "E") && (closing == ">"))) {
        p = Person_with_email(surname, name, email);
}
    return is;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person_with_telephone &p) {
    string opening, s, surname, f, name, t, telephone, test_token;

    if ((is >> opening >> s >> surname >> f >> name >> t) && (opening == "<person") && (s == "S") && (f == "N") && (t == "T")) {
        if ((is >> test_token) && (test_token == "+")) {
            is >> telephone;
}
        else {
            telephone = test_token;
        }

        p = Person_with_telephone(surname, name, telephone);
    }

    return is;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Person_with_telephone_email &p) {
    string opening, s, surname, f, name, t, telephone, e, email, closing, test_token;

    if ((is >> opening >> s >> surname >> f >> name >> t) && (opening == "<person") && (s == "S") && (f == "N") && (t == "T")) {
        if ((is >> test_token) && (test_token == "+")) {
            is >> telephone;
        }
        else {
            telephone = test_token;
        }

        if ((is >> e >> email >> closing) && ((e == "E") && (closing == ">"))) {
            p = Person_with_telephone_email(surname, name, telephone, email);
        }

    }
    return is;
}

Person* make_person(istream &stream) {
    Person *person_pointer = new Person;
    stream >> *person_pointer;
    return person_pointer;
}

Person_with_email* make_person_email(istream &stream) {
    Person_with_email *person_pointer = new Person_with_email;
    stream >> *person_pointer;
    return person_pointer;
}

Person_with_telephone* make_person_telephone(istream &stream) {
    Person_with_telephone *person_pointer = new Person_with_telephone;
    stream >> *person_pointer;
    return person_pointer;
}

Person_with_telephone_email* make_person_telephone_email(istream &stream) {
    Person_with_telephone_email *person_pointer = new Person_with_telephone_email;
    stream >> *person_pointer;
    return person_pointer;
}

istream &read_person(istream &in, Person * & p) {
    string input;
    getline(in, input);
    cout << "input:\n" << input;
    if (input == " ") { return in; }
    stringstream stream(input);
    string s = " S ";
    string e = " E ";
    string t = " T ";
    bool is_valid_person = false;
    bool has_t = false;
    bool has_e = false;

    if (input.find(e) != string::npos) { has_e = true; }
    if (input.find(t) != string::npos) { has_t = true; }
    if (input.find(s) != string::npos) { is_valid_person = true; }


    if (has_e && has_t) {
        cout << "e + t\n";
        Person_with_telephone_email *person_pointer = make_person_telephone_email(stream);
        p = person_pointer;
    }
    else if (has_e) {
        cout << "e\n";
        Person_with_email *person_pointer = make_person_email(stream);
        p = person_pointer;
    }
    else if (has_t) {
        cout << "t \n";
        Person_with_telephone *person_pointer = make_person_telephone(stream);
        p = person_pointer;

    }
    else if (is_valid_person) {
        cout << "is person \n";
        Person *person_pointer = make_person(stream);
        p = person_pointer;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nInvalid input.\n";
    }
    return in;
}

int main() {
    //Tests the read_person istream
    Person *p = 0;
    string ss = "<person S Smith N Tom >\n<person S Smith N Dick T +49.921.1434 >\n<person S Smith N Harry E hsmith@gmail.com >\n<person S Smith N Mary T +39.921.1434 E msmith@gmail.com >\n<person S John N John T + 33.921.1434 E jjohn@gmail.com >";
    stringstream iss(ss);
    while (read_person(iss, p) && p)
        cout << *p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXMJz.png), the way it should look is the same, but without the lines that say `NoName` and `NoSurname`.

I really have no idea why this might be happening, do you have any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Comment: What was the output supposed to look like? And can you put the actual and expected output within the question itself?

Comment: The comment before `using namespace std;` is dead wrong. Basic C++ functions are available whenever the appropriate header has been included. `using namespace std;` just makes it easier to screw up because every name in the standard library gets stuffed into the global namespace.

Comment: I can remove `using namespace std;` easily, any ideas with regards to my question?

Comment: Your `get_()` functions should be `const` because they don't change the class members.  Something like `string get_telephone() const;`.

Comment: Reduce this to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, i think that 280 lines of code for review is a bit too much :P also i cannot fully understand what do you mean by "code is printing outputs twice". it is printing two different outputs, at least thats what i see.
Now to the point, i hope it will help: you have 2 important couts:
first one in the while loop:
`cout << *p << endl;`
and the second in the body of read_person function:
`cout << "input:\n" << input;`

i have commented one of them and then printed result was totally different. as far as i understand your code, final behavior was not correct- check output with `cout << *p << endl;` commented out :)